# Huawei Ascend Y330 Mass Storage notification bar not showing

Tags: sync, usb-mass-storage, huawei-ascend-y330

I want to sync some pics from my phone onto my laptop but I can't since the drop down notification bar is not showing. This means I can't turn on the USB to connect to my laptop. I have hard reset my phone back to factory settings and it still won't show. I've been trying for 5 hours now and I can't work out how to get it to connect to my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Go to main screen
drop down menu from top while plugged into computer
click on device file manager
click device file manager (transfer and manage files with a computer

on computer, click in file manager
you should be able to see your phone
click on dcim
click on camera

This worked for me